# A real valued continuous function can be approximated by a polynomial function p(x) with rational coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am unable to solve a particular question asked in my analysis quiz .

> Question:Let f be a real valued continuous function on[-1,1] such that f(x)=-f(-x) for all x $\in$ [-1,1] . Show that for every $\epsilon$ >0 there is a polynomial p(x) with rational coefficients such that for every x$\in$[-1,1] ,

$|f(x)-p(x^{2})|<\epsilon$.

I thought of using stone wierestrauss theorem but It doesnot proves that all coefficients must be rational . f(-x)=f(x) will be equivalent to that there would be no terms with odd powers of x  .

But how can I prove that even by taking all coefficients to be rational , I will still have uniform convergence .

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is trivial. Just approximate by a polynomial with real coefficients  and then approximate the coefficients of that polynomial by rational numbers.

Comment: I have an ice-thin background in analysis, but it might be helpful to remember that there is a sequence of rationals approaching (in the sense of a limit) any real number. So I think there should be a way to formulate an argument using the Stone-Weirstrauss polynomial, and 'rationalizing' it's coefficients (i.e. for every coefficient, find a sequence of rational numbers approaching it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Stone-Weirstrass to get an approximation by a polynomial with real coefficients. Then, approximate each coefficient by a rational number to get an approximation by a polynomial with rational coefficients.